# Hopf algebra that is unimodular and counimodular but not involutory

Tags: hopf-algebras, quantum-groups, haar-measure

I'm looking for a finite-dimensional Hopf algebra (over any field) that is unimodular, has unimodular dual, but is not involutory. Is there such a thing?

Here's what I know:

- By Radford's formula, the antipode $S$ must have order 4.
- Suzuki [has constructed](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43685968) unimodular Hopf algebras over any field that are not involutory (and where $S^2$ is not even inner). My calculations so far suggest that these are not counimodular, but I still need to double-check.
- It is well-known that semisimplicity implies unimodularity. Therefore finding a cosemisimple unimodular Hopf algebra that is not involutory would be even stronger (or dually, a semisimple counimodular one).
- A [result](https://arxiv.org/abs/q-alg/9712033) of Etingof and Gelaki is that "semisimple cosemisimple" implies involutory, so this combination would be too strong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that an explicit example of such a Hopf algebra already appears at the end of Radford's seminal paper [The Order of the Antipode of a Finite Dimensional Hopf Algebra is Finite](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2373888) as Example 2.

The example is a bit too complicated to reproduce here, so let me just note that it is 8-dimensional, can be defined and has the desired properties over any field, and happens to be isomorphic to its opposite.